# Thingsboard : Transform script Error JSON

Tags: thingsboard

This is the error code that pops up in transform script thingsboard:

> javax.script.ScriptException: Script is blacklisted due to maximum
>   error count 3!

Comment: Formatted error as block-quote.

Comment: As the error-message states, your script was blacklisted due to an error. Check out the server log for infos on the reason. I'd guess that your script causes an exception somewhere.

Comment: yes, this is the best suggestion. I found my script did wrong output etc. and solved it. @lupz

Comment: how did you find out the script containing errors?

I get

2022-10-03 16:15:25,109 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-4] WARN o.t.js.api.AbstractJsInvokeService - Script invocation is blocked due to maximum error count 3, scriptId 78aee53d-f8b0-4024-ad50-bb7f044ea920!

but don't know how to point out which script is referenced by the above scriptId.

Anyone can help?

Seppax